# What is the symbolism of the flying cars?

Tags: plot-explanation, grease

Can someone please explain the flying car to me at the end of the movie, and how no one seems to act as if the car taking off with Danny and Sandy is anything out of the ordinary?

Is this symbolic of anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The car which they take off in at the end of the movie is the *fantasy* version of the car the Thunderbirds sing about during *Greased Lightning* and not the white car which gets torn up during the race. The Greased Lightning car, being a fantasy car, is a way of saying at the end of the movie that Danny and Sandy's dreams have come true: they will live happily ever after, or so they want the audience to believe. They ride off into the sunset together and everyone is happy for them. None of the other characters see anything wrong with it because it is a fantasy world in Danny, Sandy, and the audience's eyes, the rest of them are just seeing it as it is. At least that is my take on it.